# When does it make sense to have move constructor but not move assignment?

Tags: c++

It appears to be that normally move constructor and move assignment are defined or deleted together.

When does it make sense to have move constructor but no {move assignment, copy constructor, copy assignment}? Could u give a use case?

```cpp
class S {
public:
  S();
  S(...);
  
  S(S&) = delete;
  S(S&& rhs);
  S& operator(S&) = delete;
  S& operator(S&&) = delete;
private:
  ...
};
```

Comment: I'm sure that there are application-specific use cases. That would depend on the application, of course.

Comment: Hi @SamVarshavchik I'd like to see one such case.

Comment: Streams come to mind.  They are not assignable but they can be moved.  Also, things that store a reference.

Comment: @NathanOliver Streams can be move assigned. But I'm looking for an example where move constructor is allowed but move assignment is not. :)

Comment: Maybe for object that should not be mutable once created... but you won't have regular assignment in such case.